# How to retrieved specific data from three different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i have 3 tables, every table contains the different information of student(e.g personal detail, course detail, academic details etc), in which students have 4 different category(SC, ST, OBC and Gen). i want to retrieve the student list according to there category and Plus2Percentage.
eg.
1. i want to retrieve 2 students from SC category whose Plus2Percentage is >= 60,
then
i want to retrieve 2 students from ST category whose Plus2Percentage is >= 65,
then
i want to retrieve 1 students from OBC category whose Plus2Percentage is >= 60,
then
i want to retrieve 2 students from All 4(SC, ST, OBC and Gen) category whose Plus2Percentage is >= 70, but in this i dont want to retrieve those students info who has been already retrieved.(e.g those two student from SC Category who has been already retrieved from very step and so on from the ST OBC category)

**[Table1]**:

```
|  Roll No   | Applicant Name|   Gender   | Category   | Father's Name  |
|------------|---------------|------------|------------|----------------|
|     001    |          A    |          M |      SC    |      as        |
|     002    |          B    |          F |      ST    |      hg        |
|     003    |          C    |          F |      ST    |      yj        |
|     004    |          D    |          M |      OBC   |      uy        |
|     005    |          E    |          F |      SC    |      bn        |
|     006    |          F    |          M |      OBC   |      kl        |
|     007    |          E    |          F |      Gen   |      bn        |
|     008    |          F    |          M |      OBC   |      vg        |
|     009    |          E    |          F |      Gen   |      gh        |
|     010    |          F    |          M |      SC    |      we        |
|------------|---------------|------------|------------|----------------|
```

**[Table2]**:

```
|     ID     |    Semester   |   Major    | Applied Course|
|------------|---------------|------------|---------------|
|     001    |          1    |    English |      B.A      |
|     002    |          1    |    English |      B.A      |
|     003    |          1    |    History |      B.A      |
|     004    |          1    |    botany  |      B.Sc     |
|     005    |          1    |    Hindi   |      B.A      |
|     006    |          1    |    History |      B.A      |
|     007    |          1    |    Maths   |      B.A      |
|     008    |          1    |    Hindi   |      B.A      |
|     009    |          1    |    History |      B.A      |
|     010    |          1    | Pol.Science|      B.A      |
|------------|---------------|------------|---------------|
```

**[Table3]**:

```
|     ID     |Plus2Percentage|
|------------|---------------|
|     001    |         60    |
|     002    |         65    |
|     003    |         70    |
|     004    |         73    |
|     005    |         87    |
|     006    |         91    |
|     007    |         59    |
|     008    |         78    |
|     009    |         88    |
|     010    |         57    |
|------------|---------------|-
```

**[Output]**:

```
|   Roll No  |Plus2Percentage|  Category |
|------------|---------------|-----------|
|     005    |         87    |    SC     |
|     001    |         60    |    SC     |
|     003    |         70    |    ST     |
|     002    |         65    |    ST     |
|     006    |         91    |   OBC     |
|     009    |         88    |   Gen     |
|     008    |         78    |   OBC     |
|------------|---------------|-----------|
```

- 2 Students from SC Category whose Percentage is above or equal to 60%.
  Roll No 005 and 001 from sc.
- 2 Students from ST Category whose Percentage is above or equal to 65%.
  Roll No. 002 and 003 from st.
- 1 Students from OBC Category whose Percentage is above or equal to 60%.
  Roll No. 006 from OBC
  and
- 2 Students from all category whose percentage is above 70%, but excluding previously retrieved students.
  Roll No. 009 and 008 from all over

**Previously working code,when i was retrieving data from1 table ,instead of 3 Tables**:

WITH PRIMARY_CHOICE AS ( 
    SELECT 
        RollNo, 
        ApplicantName, 
        FatherName, 
        Gender, 
        Major,
        Category, 
        Plus2Percentage 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            RollNo, 
            ApplicantName, 
            FatherName, 
            Gender, 
            Semester, 
            Major, 
            AppliedCourse, 
            Category, 
            Plus2Percentage, 
            row_number() over (partition by Category, Semester, Major, AppliedCourse order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn 
        FROM [College Management System].[dbo].[ApplicantPersonalDetail]
    ) as T 
    WHERE 
        rn <= CASE 
                WHEN Category='SC' AND Semester='1'  AND AppliedCourse= 'B.A' AND Plus2Percentage >= '60' THEN '2'
                WHEN Category='ST' AND Semester= '1'  AND AppliedCourse= 'B.A' AND Plus2Percentage >= '65'THEN '2'
                WHEN Category='OBC' AND Semester= '1'  AND AppliedCourse= 'B.A' AND Plus2Percentage >= '60' THEN '1'
                ELSE 0 
            END 
) 
SELECT 
    RollNo, 
    ApplicantName, 
    FatherName, 
    Gender, 
    Major, 
    Category, 
    Plus2Percentage 
FROM PRIMARY_CHOICE 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    RollNo, 
    ApplicantName, 
    FatherName, 
    Gender, 
    Major, 
    Category, 
    Plus2Percentage 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        RollNo, 
        ApplicantName, 
        FatherName, 
        Gender, 
        Semester, 
        Major, 
        AppliedCourse, 
        Category, 
        Plus2Percentage, 
        row_number() over (partition by Semester, Major1, AppliedCourse  order by Plus2Percentage desc) as rn  
    FROM [College Management System].[dbo].[ApplicantPersonalDetail] x 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        select 1 from primary_choice y  
        where x.RollNo = y.RollNo
    ) 
) AS T2  
WHERE 
    rn <= 2 
    AND Semester = @semester 
    AND AppliedCourse = 'B.A' 
    AND Plus2Percentage >= 70 
order by Plus2Percentage desc

Comment: lemme tell you few things first, the code i have is working one, but that time i had only 1 table,instead of 3 tables. all the information was stored in 1 table.After making the changes in DB, i don't know how make changes in query

Comment: You are saying you wrote all that code, but don't know how to join those three tables and reuse that code?

Comment: i tried to use join but not geting anything... somebody helps me in this.

Comment: Raj can u help me this???

Comment: what do you mean with "Not getting anything"?
did you try to join the tables?
`select * from table1 as t1 
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.RollNo = t2.id
inner join table3 as t3 on t2.id = t3.id`

Comment: yes i did..n its giving error: "The multi-part identifier could not be bound."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the output but the query cost is high, if you have lots of data it populating every mins into your database than this query might not support the execution time.

I have used CTE table and UNION clauses for generating your output  - 
I have not used your table2 because there is no data required from that table in the output or is not dependent on table2

SQL SELECT CODE - you can replace your table and column names accordingly - 
**EDIT AFTER THE COMMENTS :- SOLUTION IS CHANGED INTO A STROED PROCEDURE READING DATA FROM TABLE VARIABLE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SelectCategorywiseData 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @tbl_LIST TABLE (RollNo int, [Plus2Percentage] int, Category varchar(10));

    WITH CTE AS 
    (
      SELECT A.RollNo, P.Percentage AS [Plus2Percentage], A.Category
      , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Category ORDER BY P.Percentage DESC) AS Rank 
      FROM APPLICANT A INNER JOIN  Plus2Percentage P ON A.RollNo = P.ID
    )


    INSERT INTO @tbl_LIST
    SELECT RollNo, Plus2Percentage as [Plus2Percentage], Category 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE rank <= 
    CASE 
        WHEN Category='SC' AND [Plus2Percentage] >= '60' THEN '2' 
        WHEN Category='ST' AND [Plus2Percentage] >= '60' THEN '2' 
        WHEN Category='OBC' AND [Plus2Percentage] >= '55' THEN '1' 
    ELSE 0 
    End


    INSERT INTO @tbl_LIST
    SELECT TOP 2 A.RollNo, P.Percentage as [Plus2Percentage], A.Category 
    FROM APPLICANT A INNER JOIN  Plus2Percentage P ON A.RollNo = P.ID
    WHERE Percentage > 70 and RollNo NOT IN (SELECT RollNo FROM @tbl_LIST) ORDER BY P.Percentage DESC

    SELECT * FROM @tbl_LIST 
END
```

What you will need to do is - create a temp table which will hold the data of first 5 records for SC, ST, OBC Category

Then Insert the records for all the category TOP 2 records order by percentage desc where Rollno is not in temp table. so that duplicates will be excluded and you will get the data.

`ORDER BY` SHOULD NOT BE USED AS ORDERING THE DATA CAN BE DONE LATER - IT COST THE EXECUTION TIME.

I will explain the USE of all the clauses here:

1. CTE - used to identify the row number (Ranking the records based on Percentage and grouping on Category)
2. Using CTE to select the data with individual conditional checks for Category and min. percentage.
3. Using UNION to get only distinct records as the final output.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RollNo, Plus2Percentage, Category 
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN Table3 b on a.rollno=b.id
WHERE a.category='SC' and b.Plus2Percentage>=60
```

That should be enough for the first three bullets. The fourth one is a matter of either setting up the predicate or encapsulating a union of the first three and then doing a NOT IN.

Although I do feel it difficult to believe that someone who knows enough SQL to use `ROW_NUMBER` cannot troubleshoot a `JOIN`.

Comment: i want the exact number of student from query..e.g i want 5 students from sc category and 10 students from st category, how this is possible with your query..i ll appreciate your help ..all i want to use join in working query.. and its not only me behind that query..sumbody helps me in this

Comment: How do you decide which 5 or 10 students you need to select? Highest percentage? If any of them have the same percentage, you will need to add an additional sort of some kind. What would that be?

Comment: if any of them have same percentage then we need to sort them on category basis..eg. if 2 student 1 from SC and 1 from OBC, have same percentage then i OBC student ll be preferred first.